# Midas sucker punch

Tags: magic, economy, apocalypse

One fine day Loki decided to grant everyone on Earth today a gift of wealth: one only has to deliver a blow catching the recipient off guard to turn the victim into gold nuggets.

My question is how will this effect our economy and probably the fate of the human race?

Note: regardless of the force, so long as each hit connects the victim will then undergo the transmutation instantaneously. No layers of protection can negate this attack, meaning it will also work on the hulk buster where there is another suit inside it. Actually there is another catch: after each murder all present will immediately suffer amnesia, so how will anyone know the trick?

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase the last part of the question a bit: I have no idea what you mean with the Hulk Buster thing.

Comment: @Thomas Jacobs suppose I sneak up on Tony while he is wearing both his Mk series suit and hulk buster at the same time and I hammered him gently the result is a giant pot of golds.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs I believe he's referring to the recent _Avengers 2_ movie in which Tony Stark built a suit (named Veronica) that amplified his combat abilities in order to neutralize the Hulk.

Comment: @user6760 So if I get that right, I could just nugget a whole lot of people by touching say a bus or other vehicle or even a building? At least the bus is very similar to a hulkbuster. Only difference being it can actually hold more people (and is not bipedal)

Comment: @Evo_Kaer you seems to catch on rather quickly

Comment: The primary issues caused by this will be economic, short of pivotal important people being turned to gold. People will quickly cotton on that a fat person is a more lucrative target. Look at Colonial Spanish Silver supplies, Chinas move to use only silver coinage as currency at the same time period, and deflation for inspiration, especially wreckless quantative easing ( Weimar republic, Zimbabwe )

Comment: It might work better if the substance created changed regularly to whatever is valuable. Gold would lose it's value almost immediately. 

There is 564,900,000 tonnes of human flesh in the world.
There is 155,244 tonnes of gold.  
After day 1 gold is no longer rare hence is no longer worth much at all.

Comment: Does "Present" include people watching by television?

Comment: @colmde since Loki is responsible for adulterating memories and only for those who have seen the transmutation taking place even rewinding a recording think of [The Ring 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_%282002_film%29)

Comment: This amnesia thing - how much do people forget? Are people left wondering where Steve went and where this pile of gold came from? Do they lose all memories of everything ever? Is the person who threw the punch affected? We really need to know more details about this.

Comment: If anyone cares, the Hulk Buster has a history that goes back before *Avengers 2.* But not being a comic nerd, I don't care enough to post any links.

Comment: This is a question of the sort: ["Hey, I came up with a fun concept, now please write my world/story for me"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868). Putting a close vote on this for being much too broad.

Comment: @MichaelK This question is also 26 months old, more than eight times older than the Meta question you linked. We generally avoid closing questions under these constraints. Not sure why it was edited (other than Secespitus being our resident editor-in-chief).

Comment: @Frostfyre Yes that may be the case; I am not writing this to lecture the questioner but rather to inform people that are coming reading this question now The fact that it **is* popping up is rather a testament to its relevance and longevity. :)

Comment: @Frostfyre As the accepted answer to [your question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3383/should-we-close-old-questions) says, old questions should be closed if they are getting attention. Similarly we should provide an explanation for why a question was closed, which is exactly what MichaelK did.

Comment: @sphennings I was also the third one to VTC this question, because I recognized it had become active again and didn't measure up to our current standards. Doesn't explain why it was made active again in the first place. My point being that we shouldn't be actively looking for old questions for the purpose of closing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First hour

In the first few minutes, thousands of people are weeping at their close relative's gold remains, having jokingly punched them while off-guard. Thousands more are turned to gold by practical joke punches and reassuring slugs. Basically, lots of people die.

#### First day

Word gets around, making all the news channels, all the papers, all the radio channels and word of mouth. *Lots* of seclusion and mistrust spreads as an **extremely efficient and stealthy** assassination method was just created *with no evidence*. The less scrupulous take advantage and kill their boss, annoying neighbor, and anyone else they hate. Oh, and there's panic, lots of panic.

#### Second day

I would bet martial law might go into effect, with accidental murder committed and plenty more intentional ones coming. School is definitely out while hospital and military quarantines take effect and most (hopefully) don't show up for work. Expect less pedestrians, but more automotive migration traffic.

#### First week

IMO the chaos would not necessarily bring about the apocalypse, depending directly on the level of government control, magnitude of riots and loss of population, but lets go the fun route.

Riots. Riots and murder and looting and in general collapse of trust (and thus collapse of infrastructure) takes place. People are making plans to stay at the most secure location they know of while the government attempts to place laws and direct the masses in general.

#### First month

Now were at the apocalypse stage. Most destruction comes directly from vandalism, (i.e. Probably no nukes launched from this) but expect terrorist groups to have a field <strike>day</strike> year. Mass migration continues and mass murder as well, not only from gold-punches (because why would we stop using guns?).

From then on, progress is made in the [fashion](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ApocalypseHow) [well explored by media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_apocalyptic_films). Groups form, groups die, drama and all that. Oh and as @Burki said, gold is worthless now.

Comment: In short this is much worst than zombie apocalypse! dwarfing nuclear holocaust and second only to planet killer asteriod!

Comment: Not to mention a lot of kids die as they punch each other during play. Also some newborns are killed while doctor slap them. That should create a large age gap between 0 and 15 year olds.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the question if anyone actually knew the trick: There would soon be a lot less people, and some (highly suspicious) large amounts of gold.

This would cause a lot of confusion, and the gold price will drop massively.

I assume that this effect will stay (at least as long as your Loki does not remove it again), so that every time someone punches someone else and catching the victim off guard you get less people and more gold.

The people who do a fairly high amount of punching are typically small children. That said: there would very soon be a lot less children about. And children suddenly trying to carry large amounts of gold, especially in a context where an other child just went missing under very mysterious circumstances, will cause a lot more chaos and confusion.

I think that apart from the fact that gold would pretty soon be more of a nuisance than a valuable metal, the human race would die out pretty quickly, with an upper time limit of maybe two generations.

Comment: I'm trying to create a world where the remaining populations are second guessing each other and live in fear every moment unless...